# Nav Drawer Adaptability on another device

Tags: android, xml, android-listview, compatibility

I've created my first app and I now am checking how it looks on a set of several devices.
I've found 1 error though :

[image]

[image]

The picture of the top is the result on my **Galaxy S4** while the bottom one is from an **Xperia Z**

As you can see the results are different even though the [Xperia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sony_Xperia_Z) is a **1920*1080 443 ppi**, juste like the Galaxy S4...

On the Sony Xperia Z, the text isn't centered but **sightly under** instead.

Here is my custom List structure :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/list_selector">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc_list_item_icon"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_home"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

So why would they be different, what, beyoud the screen resolution should be taken into account ? What could make these changes ?

**Thanks a lot for all your help !**

Comment: Remove margins top and bottom and try with gravity. Then only you get perfect solution.

Comment: Indeed that worked but I got everything so tight... So I added padding top and bottom to the relative layout and it worked like a charm. Do you wanna write an answer so I can validate you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this in your textview

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:textColor="@color/list_item_title"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="TEST"
    android:paddingRight="40dp"/>
```